# Tricky multiple transformations that create new dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataframe, df, where I would like to perform calculations and create new fields from.

**Data**

```
   location1    date1   type1   value1  positions   location2   type2   date2   value2  
   sel1         Q1.22   lap1    10      50          sel1         fr1    Q1.22   10  
   sel1         Q1.22   d1      20      50          NaN          NaN    NaN     NaN 
   sel1         Q1.22   d2      10      50          NaN          NaN    NaN     NaN 
   vel1         Q1.22   a1      5       100         NaN          NaN    NaN     NaN 
   vel1         Q1.22   a2      5       100         NaN          NaN    NaN     NaN 
   vel1         Q2.22   v1      1       100         NaN          NaN    NaN     NaN 
   vel1         Q2.22   v1      1       100         NaN          NaN    NaN     NaN 
   tel1         Q3.22   b1      35      5           tel1         d1     Q3.22   2   
   tel1         Q3.22   b2      35      5           NaN          NaN    NaN     NaN 
   gel1         Q4.22   y1      10      80          gel1         z1     Q4.22   2   
   gel1         Q4.22   y2      15      80          gel1         z1     Q4.22   2
```

**Desired**

```
location    date    consumed    retro   finalconsumed   re_space    positions   
sel1        Q1.22   40          10      30              48          50  
vel1        Q1.22   10          0       10              98          100 
vel1        Q2.22   2           0       2               96          100 
tel1        Q3.22   70          2       68              4           5   
gel1        Q4.22   25          4       21              80          80
```

**Doing**

1. I am trying to group by location1 and date1 and then sum value1 and create a ‘consumed’ column and then sum value2 and create a ‘retro’ column (group by location2 and date2)
2. I am also trying to create a ‘final’ column which then subtracts the newly created ‘consumed’ from the newly created ‘retro’ column
3. Finally I am trying to group by **positions, location1 and date1** and subtract the count of **type1** from **positions** and add the count of type2.  This is the 're_space' column

   for 'sel1', there are 3 counts of 'type1' and there is 1 count of  'type2' (making sure its grouped by location and date)

   for 'vel1', (Q1.22) there are 2 counts of 'type1', and 0 counts for 'type2'

   for 'vel1', (Q2.22) there are 2 counts of 'type1', and 0 counts for 'type2'

**Step 3 example**

vel1, Q1.22
(100 - 2) + 0 = 98

we have 100 positions for vel1 in Q1.22, and then we remove 2 and add 0 (since type 2 is NaN)

vel1, Q2.22
(98  - 2)  + 0  = 96

Now we have 98 positions in vel1, since we already subtracted 2 from this prior. 98 - 2 is 96

Starting with 98 because this is our new starting number for the positions

*Step 3 involves subtracting and adding*

```
          def f(x):
              d = {'consumed': [x['value1'].sum()],
                   'retro': [x['value2'].sum()],
                   'finalconsumed': [x['value1'].sum() - x['value2'].sum()],
                   're_space': [x['positions'].mean() - x['type1'].count() + x['type2'].count()]}
              return pd.DataFrame(d)

          u=df.groupby(['location1', 'date1']).apply(f).reset_index()
```

A SO member originally helped me with this and it works beautifully. I have since updated and the update involves subtracting the count from the base position so that each quarter gets updated with the correct position count.
I believe I may have to introduce a .cumulative count script

```
.cumsum())
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. I am still researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a minor change in function:

```
def f(x):
    d = {'consumed': [x['value1'].sum()],
         'retro': [x['value2'].sum()],
         'finalconsumed': [x['value1'].sum() - x['value2'].sum()],
         're_space': [x['type2'].count() - x['type1'].count()]}  # <<< HERE
    return pd.DataFrame(d)

out = df.groupby(['location1', 'date1', 'positions']) \
        .apply(f).reset_index().drop(columns='level_3')

# Compute re_space with cumsum
out['re_space'] = out['positions'] + out.groupby('location1')['re_space'].cumsum()
```

```
>>> out
  location1  date1  positions  consumed  retro  finalconsumed  re_space
0      gel1  Q4.22         80        25    4.0           21.0        80
1      sel1  Q1.22         50        40   10.0           30.0        48
2      tel1  Q3.22          5        70    2.0           68.0         4
3      vel1  Q1.22        100        10    0.0           10.0        98
4      vel1  Q2.22        100         2    0.0            2.0        96
```

Comment: Ok thank you I will try. This same logic should work for other locations as well right? Thank you

Comment: Yes, it's worked for other locations. Think to check the column `re_space` of `out` variable before override it with `cumsum`.

Comment: am wondering if you could provide some suggestion to my latest post. I am still researching this and tweaking. Thank you